# Is there a way for objects to pass along methods that can be shared automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I seem to come into alot of circumstances where when I refactor a class, I am often creating several methods that do nothing but pass along the information to the new (for now) subordinate class.  So say I have Obj1 and it has 15 methods, and I end up moving 4 into Obj2.  Now I have 4 methods in Obj1 that are just:

```
def foo arg1, arg2
   @obj2.foo arg1, arg2
end

def bar arg1
   @obj2.bar arg1
end
```

I would think there could be a one line way to give access to these methods that are one level removed.  Like:

```
 foo, bar = @obj2.foo, @object2.bar
```

or

```
@obj2.release(:foo, :bar)`
```

It would have to pass along all method arguments of course.  It looks like this is a concept in python called a descriptor, but I don't see anything equivalent in Ruby.. is there?

Comment: instance variables are available in all functions of a same class. Could you give a clearer example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Rails (you tagged it) you can use the [delegate method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate):

```
class Widget
  delegate :foo, :bar, :to => '@obj2'
end
```

Then calling the foo method on an instance of Widget will just call it on whatever @obj2 is.